# Alternativa ao Miktex

Tags: r, latex

Olá. Estou fazendo um documento em RMD no Rstudio e gostaria de exporta-lo para word ou pdf. Vi que para isso eu preciso instalar o Miktex. No entanto, mesmo seguindo todos os passos ( o tutorial mais resumido está [aqui](https://medium.com/@sorenlind/create-pdf-reports-using-r-r-markdown-latex-and-knitr-on-windows-10-952b0c48bfa9), que sintetiza o que eu encontrei em vários outros lugares ) eu não consigo terminar de instalar o programa, pois ele não consegue extrair / instalar o arquivo initexmf.exe . Procurei em vários fóruns mas não encontrei uma solução definitiva para resolver esse problema e instalar o Miktex. Eu trabalho com o Windows 10 64 bit.

Alguém sabe como eu posso terminar de instalar o Miktex ou se existe alguma alternativa para eu conseguir exportar o RMD para word?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ao contrário do Linux e macOS, as distribuições de LaTeX para o Windows são um lixo. Quase sempre dá algum conflito e é muito difícil consertar sem acesso a um bom terminal, coisa que o Windows não tem.

O que tenho sugerido nos últimos meses pra quem quer usar R e LaTeX no Windows é a instalação do pacote [TinyTex](https://yihui.name/tinytex/). Sim, é um pacote pro R, mas ele instala uma versão do Tex Live que funciona muito bem. Instalar ela é muito fácil.

Em primeiro lugar, desinstale o MikTex.

Em segundo lugar, rode os seguintes comandos dentro do `R`:

```
library(devtools)
install_github(c("yihui/tinytex", "rstudio/rmarkdown"))
tinytex::install_tinytex()
```

Vão aparecer um aviso e duas mensagens de erro durante a execução do segundo comando. Ignore-as dando OK no prompt que aparecer e pronto. Após os procedimentos necessários, seu computador vai estar com o LaTeX instalado.

Feche e abra o RStudio antes de compilar o relatório pela primeira vez.

É basicamente isso. O mínimo do LaTeX vai estar instalado no teu PC. Caso mais pacotes sejam necessários, o próprio TinyTex vai instalar o que for preciso, desde que o teu computador esteja conectado à internet.

Vai ser possível criar relatório em RMarkdown dentro do RStudio ou compilar arquivos .tex a partir de editor de textos externos, como TexWorks e WinEdt.

Comment: Marcus muito obrigada! Funcionou perfeitamente!